# Fantasy series about search to find and reunite a mythical sword, shield and helmet

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for help identifying a series I read in the mid 2000's which was originally published in English.

- There were 3 or 4 books in the series
- It was a fantasy series aimed at probably young teens
- I think there were two main characters who were in their teens (I think one boy and one girl)
- Something was happening in their world (which I'm fairly sure was a pre-industrial world so no electricity etc.), a war or conflict was coming and they had to find a missing sword, helmet, shield (and possibly one other thing) which would help them overcome it
- These objects were hidden in different places in different cities
- One of the objects was hidden at the top of a really big water fountain
- From memory the covers were quite plain, a coloured background with the title and author, and a picture/drawing of the object they were searching for in that particular book in the centre

It's not much to go on, but any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you remember if the setting had anything memorable about it? Magic? Nonhumans?  
And, in the same vein, the heroes travelled from city to city, do you remember what method of transportation they used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### *The Golden Armor*

This series, written by Richard Brown, comprises *The Helmet*, *The Shield*, *The Spurs*, and *The Sword*.

There is a conflict for which they need those items. To quote [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2367232.The_Helmet):

> Cassie and Keiron have spend all their life on the freezing North Island, where their life is happy and settled. But a strange prince has come to their shores, a man with darkness in his eyes and ice in his veins. And now the race is on to find the magical Golden Helmet.

The images are as described.

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thanks!